# Should I use CRITICAL_SECTION or not?

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface, locking

I have a program which has a Ui with which users choose the way to display and do small configurations. It also has a background procedure, which continuously reads data from the network and update the data to display.

Now I put them in one process:
background procedure:

```
    STATE MainWindow::Rcv()
    {

    DeviceMAP::iterator dev;

    for(dev= dev_map.begin(); dev!= dev_map.end(); dev++)
    {


        dev->second.rcvData();//receive data from the network, the time can be ignored.

        BitLog* log = new BitLog();
        dev->second.parseData(log);


        LogItem* logItem = new LogItem();
        logItem->time = QString::fromLocal8Bit(log->rcvTime.c_str());
        logItem->name = QString::fromLocal8Bit(log->basicInfo.getName().c_str());
        logItem->PIN = QString::fromLocal8Bit(log->basicInfo.getPIN().c_str()).toShort();

        delete log;
        add_logItem(logItem);

    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

add_logItem:

```
void MainWindow::add_logItem(LogItem* logItem)
{


    writeToFile(logItem);

    Device* r = getDevbyPIN(QString::number(logItem->PIN));

    if(r == NULL)return;

    devInfo_inside_widget::States state = logItem->state;

    bool bool_list[portsNum_X];
    for(int i =0; i < portsNum_X; i++)
    {
        bool_list[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < portsNum; i++)
    {
        bool_list[i] = (logItem->BITS[i/8] >> (7 - i%8)) & 0x1;
    }

    r->refresh(state, logItem->time, bool_list);//update data inside...state, time , BITS...

    IconLabel* icl = getIConLabelByDev(r);//update data
    icl->refresh(state);


    logDisplayQueue.enqueue(logItem);//write queue here

    int size = logDisplayQueue.size();

    if(size > 100)
    {
        logDisplayQueue.dequeue();//write queue here
    }

}
```

The section above has not dealt with any ui operations yet, but when user push a radio button in the ui, the program has to filter the data in the queue and display it in the table widget:

ui operations:

```
void MainWindow::filter_log_display(bool bol)
{

    row_selectable = false;
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(0);//delete table items all
    row_selectable = true;

    int size_1 = logDisplayQueue.size() - 1;

    ui->tableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(0);

    if(size_1+1 < 100)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(size_1 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(100);//display 100 rows at most
    }


    if(bol)//filter from logDisplayQueue and display unworking-state-log rows
    {

        int  index = 0;
        for(int queue_i = size_1; queue_i >= 0; queue_i--)
        {

            LogItem* logItem = (LogItem*)logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i); // read queue here

            if(logItem->state == STATE_WORK || logItem->state == STATE_UN)continue;


            QString BITS_str = bits2Hexs(logItem->BITS);

            ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(logItem->time));//time
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(logItem->name));//name
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(BITS_str));//BITS

            if(queue_i == oldRowItemNo)ui->tableWidget->selectRow(index);
            index++;
        }

        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(index);

    }
    else//display all rows
    {

        for(int queue_i = size_1, index = 0; queue_i >= 0; queue_i--, index++)
        {

            LogItem* logItem = (LogItem*)logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i);                      //read queue here

            QString BITS_str = bits2Hexs(logItem->BITS);//
            finish = clock();

            ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(logItem->time));//time
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(logItem->name));//name
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(BITS_str));//BITS

            if(queue_i == oldRowItemNo)ui->tableWidget->selectRow(index);

        }



    }

}
```

So the queue is quite samll and the background procedure is quite frequent(nearly 500 times per sec). That is, the queue will be written 500 times in 1 sec, but displayed time from time by the user.
I want to split the functions into two threads and run them together, one rev and update data, one display.
If i do not use any lock or mutex, the user may get the wrong data, but if i force the write-data procedure enter critical section and leave critical section everytime, it will be a heavy overload. :)
Should I use CRITICAL_SECTION or something else, any suggestions related?(my words could be verbose for you :) , i only hope for some hints :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put "Recv" function in another QObject derived class, put it under other QThread not main gui thread and connect "logItemAdded(LogItem* item)" signal to main window's "addLogItem(LogItem* item)" slot.

for just quick and dirty hint my conceptual code follows.

```
 #include <QObject>

class Logger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Logger(QObject* parent=0);
    virtual ~Logger();
signals:
    void logItemAdded(LogItem* logItem);
public slots:
protected:
    void Rcv()
    {
        // ...

        // was "add_logItem(logItem)"
        emit logItemAdded(logItem);
    }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(...)
{
    Logger logger = new Logger;

    // setup your logger

    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    logger->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck.